# Переопределение grid при задание textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-toolkit

У меня есть главный интерфейс где выводятся сообщения в listview. Этот интерфейс разбит на 2 grid 'a. Грид я разбиваю таким образом:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions> 
    <RowDefinition Height="280"/> 
    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/> 
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

в первом у меня Listview во втором textbox.
Как написать код, чтобы текст бокс при написании текста больше нескольких строк рос вверх и двигал грид 0?
https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/11/18/65dd3404bd7e16f43d2a6b048be3874a-full.png

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="280"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ScrollViewer  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Name="ScrolChat" PreviewMouseWheel="ScrolChat_PreviewMouseWheel">
        <ListView ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MyListView}" SelectionChanged="ListMessage_SelectionChanged"
              ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
              Name="ListMessage" Grid.Row="0">
        </ListView>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  Grid.Row="1">

        <TextBox   TextWrapping="Wrap"
                  Name="txtblock" Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                  Margin="4"/>

        <Button Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}"                     
                Margin="0 4 20 0"   
                Click="Button_Click_1">
            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Send" />
        </Button>          
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Установите текстбоксу `TextWrapping`

Comment: установил уже до написания вопроса на stack. Каким образом это поможет переопределить размеры grid 0?!

Comment: Покажите разметку

Comment: @Андрей правил в вопрос

Comment: Текст сейчас переносится на новую строку?

Comment: @Андрей да, вот как это выглядит сейчас https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/11/18/70aaa9a35e44a8e28f15b6e55ab9e00c-full.png

Comment: Так, а что именно не устраивает?

Comment: @Андрей пример, вот вк до заполнения: https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/11/18/d68f96e24809f621fedcedeab56fbbc2-full.png вот после https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/11/18/4eec101f1d3b07302a9851e6383cfe0c-full.png видите? textbox переопределяет размеры свои и грида, в котором отображаются сообщения, а не ползет вниз за интерфейс, и мне нужно так же сделать

Comment: Что в вашем скрине "уползло за интерфейс": https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/11/18/70aaa9a35e44a8e28f15b6e55ab9e00c-full.png ? Выразите мысль точнее

Comment: @Андрей вот я пишу сообщение в несколько строк https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/11/18/488c9f049b6cb012e7639fdae9ad776f-full.png курсор textbox 'a за пределами интерфейса, это четко видно после растяжения окна вниз https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/11/18/89f1cae1da976762345898a0679ada14-full.png

Comment: А если у первой строки грида сделать не фиксированный размер: `Height="*"`?

Comment: @Андрей вроде пробовал это да видимо криво, как - то пробовал. Cпасибо помогло:)

Comment: Отлично, оформил ответом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас первая строка грида имеет фиксированную высоту, потому фреймворк не имеет права менять ее. Ваше решение установить высоту, занимающую все доступное пространство: `Height="*"`